# JavaScript scope issue

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following piece of javascript but for some scoping reason the "names" that is returned from myfunc is empty.

```
var myfunc = function(client, id) {
  var names = new Array();
  client.query(
    'SELECT stuff FROM mytable WHERE id="'+id+'"',
    (function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      for (result in results) {
        // This prints fine
        console.log(results[result].name);
        names[result] = results[result].name;
      }
      client.end();
    })
  );
  // The following returns empty
  return names;
}

console.log(myfunc(1,2));
```

How can I make it break out of scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's empty because the call to your "query" function is **asynchronous**.  The function you pass into it won't be run until the results are available. Therefore, your "myfunc" function returns immediately, long before that callback function is invoked.

Using Javascript in a browser, you have to think in those terms. Instead of expecting your "names" to be ready immediately, change "myfunc" so that you pass *it* a callback function to be invoked when the names are actually available:

```
var myfunc = function(client, id, whenFinished) {
  var names = new Array();
  client.query(
    'SELECT stuff FROM mytable WHERE id="'+id+'"',
    (function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      for (result in results) {
        // This prints fine
        console.log(results[result].name);
        names[result] = results[result].name;
      }
      client.end();
      if (whenFinished) whenFinished(names); // callback
     })
  );
};
```

Now when you call your function, instead of expecting the "names" as a return value, you'll pass in *another* function that will act on the list of names:

```
myfunc(1, 2, function(names) { console.log(names); });
```

Answer (score 1):

If **client.query(...)** is asynchronous, then the **selectCb** function would not have run and **names** would not have changed by the time **myfunc** returns. You need to redesign **myfunc** to return **names** asynchronously (by, for example, accepting a function parameter which it calls at the end of **selectCb**).

Comment: Could you give me a concrete example or point me to some reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = new Array();

var myfunc = function(client, id) {

  client.query(
    'SELECT stuff FROM mytable WHERE id="'+id+'"',function selectCb(err, results, fields)
  {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      for (result in results) {
        // This prints fine
        console.log(results[result].name);
        names[result] = results[result].name;
      }
      client.end();
    }
  );
  // The following returns empty
  return names;
}

console.log(myfunc(1,2));
```

try making names global

Comment: That won't help, I don't think.  *Eventually* the "names" array will be populated, but not immediately.